# How to ONE set of data in one page while the database having multiple sets? using mobile jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am having this project on Mobile Jquery and to be run on Safari browser on iPad. 
It is a e-assessment system where student will be able to take a quiz. 
this quiz's question to be print out each on one page and follow by next question by clicking on the 'next' button.. 
there is no fix number of question in the database therefore a loop is necessary. 
Posting the answer for marking is also another critical issue..

Anyone can enlighten me please ?

Comment: Do you want to load your questions as you go or build the whole quiz in one shot? Do you need to post the answer each time you hit next or once at the end?

Comment: It is better to load as it goes which means after the user select the desired answer then will load to a new page or via clicking 'next' butoon... Post asnwer once at the end.. thankss @jaudette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to have to load your next pages is a template jquery mobile will recognize.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header"><a href="/url/to/next/question">next</a></div>
  <div data-role="content">
    //put your question and answer here
  </div>
</div>
```

And on the last page, you need to collect all your answers and post them with ajax. You can do this easily by giving all your answers a class of `answer`, jqm keeps a cached copy of your past pages to make access faster, you can use this. If that does not work, you might have to save your answers to an array or object when you click next and serialize them instead.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: $('.answer').serialize(),
  url: "/post/answer/url"
});
```

Comment: but the question is every of my test has different number of question therefore i can't fix it into a page with individual URL. Currently i am using a while loop to loop all the question into one page.

Comment: 7@user1913025 With jqm, you can have multiple pages. Since your questions must be ordered, you can always know what page is next and link to it. You could use parameters like `/quiz/quizName?qnum=4`

Comment: can i contact u personally as i still don't get the logic..thanks @jaudette

Comment: I will set up a chat room, look up at chat and look for me.

Comment: @user1913025 [it is here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21530/jqm-one-set-of-data)

Comment: hi , can u contact me via email... here is my email. chainyeanshan@gmail.com